# Java: Array sorting

Tags: java, arrays

I need to sort an array in ascending and descending order and add its value.

Example code:

```
Integer[] c={3,2,4,1};
Integer[] c1= new Integer[3];

Arrays.sort(c);

c1=c;

System.out.print(c1[0]);

Arrays.sort(c,Collections.reverseOrder());

System.out.print(c1[0]); *\ here I'm getting different result \*
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://ideone.com/Y6k8U2

Comment: To see the full array, change your print statements to `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(c1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you're getting a different result, you just resorted the one and only array (`c1` and `c` are pointing to the same array).

I think you're confused about what `c1=c` does. It doesn't copy the array.

**Updated**

What you mean to do is:

```
Integer[] c1 = new Integer[c.length]; // note corrected size
System.arraycopy(c, 0, c1, 0, c.length);
```

Comment: Ya u r right! Plz give a solution to copy the sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

Bellow program works well

```
 public class Solution {

static Integer[] c = {3, 2, 4, 1};
static Integer[] c1 = new Integer[3];

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Arrays.sort(c);
    c1 = c;

    Arrays.sort(c, Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println("  Descending = ");
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(+ c1[i]);
        }
    Arrays.sort(c);
    System.out.println("Ascending  = " );
    for (int number : c) {
       System.out.println( number);
       }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the values of the array up.  Here is an answer showing the arrays contents step-by-step using the other suggestions for correct copying of arrays and setting c1 to the right length.

```
// Prints out array contents and sum
public static void printSumArray( Integer[] iArray){
    int iCumulativeSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print( " " + iArray[i] + " " );
        iCumulativeSum += iArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println("  Cumulative Sum = " + iCumulativeSum);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] c = {3,2,4,1,0};
    Integer[] c1 = new Integer[c.length];

    System.out.print("Original Array c:   ");
    printSumArray(c);

    Arrays.sort(c);

    System.out.print("Sorted Array c:     ");
    printSumArray(c);

    System.arraycopy(c, 0, c1, 0, c.length);
    Arrays.sort(c1,Collections.reverseOrder());


    System.out.print("Reversed Sorted c1: ");
    printSumArray(c1);      
}
```

output:

```
    Original Array c:    3  2  4  1  0   Cumulative Sum = 10
    Sorted Array c:      0  1  2  3  4   Cumulative Sum = 10
    Reversed Sorted c1:  4  3  2  1  0   Cumulative Sum = 10
```

Comment: Your code could be simplified by replacing 5 print statements with one, using `System.out.println("Original Array c: " + Arrays.asList(c))`

Answer (score 0):

Change your second line to:

```
Integer[] c1= new Integer[4];
```

If it is 3 (instead of 4) then there are only 3 spaces in the array; c1[0], c1[1] and c1[2]

Comment: You are right, that's probably what he meant to do, but it really doesn't matter, because the `c1=c` statement two lines down is discarding that array anyway.

Comment: Thats not my actual prblm. Its my typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
package sortadd;
import java.util.*;
public class Sortadd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int temp=0;
      int [] array = {3,2,1};
      int asum=0;
      int dsum=0;
      int sum=0;
      for(int i =0; i<array.length; i++){
          for(int j=i+1;j<array.length; j++){
              if(array[i]>array[j]){
                  temp=array[i];
                  array[i]=array[j];
                  array[j]=temp;
              }
          }
      }
      System.out.println("Ascending");
      for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
          System.out.println(array[i]+" ");
          asum +=array[i];
      }
      for(int i =0; i<array.length; i++){
          for(int j=i+1; j<array.length; j++){
              if(array[i]<array[j]){
                  temp=array[i];
                  array[i]=array[j];
                  array[j]=temp;
              }
          }
      }
      System.out.println("Descending");
      for(int i =0; i<array.length; i++){
          System.out.println(array[i]+" ");
          dsum+=array[i];
      }
      //sum of sorted ascending and descendin
      sum =asum+dsum;
      System.out.println("SUM"+sum);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the line,

```
Arrays.sort(c,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

You aren't actually changing the value of the array. Instead, use this line of code to change the array.

```
c1 = Arrays.sort(c,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

When you are calling just the method Arrays.sort(...), it returns a new array, but doesn't actually change the array itself. but by changing c1's values to the return of Arrays.sort(...), the array will change.

Comment: `Arrays.sort` does exactly that: "changing the value of the array". Both `Arrays.sort()` and `Collections.sort()` replace the content.